# How to read file with no-cache in Android?

Tags: android, file, cache-control

I am working on a test application on Android platform. Test the write/read speed to the sdcard. I write in C language with NDK interface.

First I write a for-loop to create 256 files with 512 random bytes in each. This part works fine. I open file with flag O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_SYNC and mode 0666. After call write, I do sync() to make sure the data is written on the card.

Then I write another 2-level for-loop to read these file to test speed. I use O_RDWR|O_SYNC to open the file. Then call read().

Here is the thing: If it is the first time I run the read part. The first loop to read take more time than the after. I'm sure it is because after the first loop, program read the cache not the real physical card.

I've tried O_DIRECT flag to read. But it error with EINVAL. In the man page for open, it says maybe it is because of this function not implement by the platform.

Do you have any idea on how to read with no-cache in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a rooted phone to disable operating-system-level caching.

https://web.archive.org/web/20120531024443/http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=SDCardSpeedTests

That also takes care to do operations large enough to overwhelm any on-card buffers.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But I really want to know is how to do this in program(better be C language). Cause the project will finally do this kind of thing. And cannot suppose phone that to be tested has the root permission and can run adb shell command.

Comment: I have try several way. But no good happened. Here is my try: I set the file size to 2048 bytes. And each time I read 512+n bytes, n is a random number between 0 to 2048-512, and copy the useful 512 byte back to buffer to compare with original ones. I thought that whatever the system will cache the content I read, so I read a different length of content to make sure the system read the actual card again. But it seems no change. I read content still in memory buffer.

Comment: Your test are at least a thousand times too small, unless what you desire to test are the buffer speeds rather than the media speed.  There is nothing in the link above that cannot be done in C (sources of dd are available), and its trivial to emulate echo, except for the permission escalation which requires a rooted device.  Probably the only way to work around that is to make the transfers larger than the device's available RAM.  Perhaps you should think about why you need to take these measurements anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I think you are right. I need to revalue the test issue. And by far, your answer is the most close to my destination.:)